# How to render multiple component inside map function in REACT?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am using switch case statement in which i am using two map function. one map function is used for word and other is used for punctuation mark. basically i want to split a word with punctuation mark.
here i face this problem in which everything is going fine but my component in not render. in if else
what should i do call this component whose name is A and B.

```
</div>
<script type="text/babel">
 class A extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
        this.state={
        }
    }

    render(){
      return (
        <div>
         {this.props.item}hello
        </div>
      )
    }
 }
 class B extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
    }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        {this.props.items}
      </div>
    )


  }
 }
 class C extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      self =this; 
      this.state = {
        cstate:true,
        renderdComp:''
      }
      this.switch =this.switch.bind(this)
      this.callComp =this.callComp.bind(this)
    }
```

callComp(item,punc,k){
        console.log("item =>",item,"punc =>",punc,"k =>",k);

```
    if(punc == '') {
     this.setState({
         renderdComp : "A"
       })   
return <A item={item}/>

    } else {
         this.setState({
         renderdComp : "B"
       })
         return <B items={item}/>

    }}
switch(stateValue) {
if(stateValue) {
    let freshItem;
    let puncItem;
    ['a;','as','df','fg'].map( function(item, i) {
        [';',':','<'].map( function (punc, j) {
            const isFoundPunc = item.indexOf(punc)
            if(isFoundPunc > -1) {
                console.log(isFoundPunc)
                freshItem = item.substr(0,isFoundPunc);
                console.log(freshItem)
                puncItem = item.substr(isFoundPunc,item.length);
                console.log(puncItem)

            } else {
               freshItem = item
                console.log(freshItem+"sec")
                puncItem = ''
                 console.log(puncItem+"sec")

            }
        })
        self.callComp(freshItem, puncItem, i)
    })
}
```

}
      render(){
        return(
          
           {this.switch(this.state.cstate)}
          
        )
      }
     }
     ReactDOM.render(,document.getElementById("container"));

Comment: You call `this.switch` inside render, but you don't return anything from this function, so nothing is rendered

Comment: so what should i do.

Comment: Try adding `return` before `['a;','as','df','fg'].map`. And before `self.callComp` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setState here in this function

```
 constructor() {
     this.callComp = this.callComp.bind(this)
     }
    callComp(item,punc,k){
        console.log("item =>",item,"punc =>",punc,"k =>",k);

        if(punc == '') {
         this.setState({
             renderdComp : "A"
           })   
    return <A item={item}/>

        } else {
             this.setState({
             renderdComp : "B"
           })
             return <B items={item}/>

        }
```

This should rerender your component C

Comment: have you changed your function to arrow function. What error are you getting

Comment: No, I am not using arrow function. I am using normal map function. I am not getting any error but component is not render. can you plz do proper change in my code. please help will be appreciated

Comment: define callComp like the way i have defined using arrow function. Or you have to bind your function callComp in constructor like this

this.callComp = this.callComp.bind(this)

Comment: nopes. That time infinite loop run. can you please give 2min and edit my real code. i updated as what you mention please look at my new updated code.